in the new update of nixos discord and spotify stopped being interacitve. How to fix that?
I think the problem started when i updated the main nixos flake. spotify and discord run perfectly the problem is i can't interact with them with neither the mouse or the keyboard. the only i could interact with spotify was playerctl. you can find my dotfiles here for more detail.
running spotify in the terminal gives me this error:
(spotify:95466): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 02:24:25.487: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
and discord had this:
[95750:0712/022508.744238:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
i don't know if these errors have anything to do with the error.
I did mess around nvidia settings lately but I think it started after the update.
